# Beginner Question: (optional) promises in combination with arrows / accessing result/error values

Tags: javascript, lambda, es6-promise

This is a simple function to create an object for my mongoDB with mongoose:

```
Item.create({ name: req.body.newItem }, function (err, res) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});
```

Now, I am learning the concept of promises. Since the [create API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) returns an optional promise, I want to work with that, for learning purpose and readability.

The way I did it is like this:

```
let newItem = Item.create(
        {name: req.body.newItem}).then(() => console.log("Success"), () => console.log("Error!"));
```

which does work. But I cheat myself here. What I actually want is to have the same code as above, that means using the `(err, small)` and incorporating that into my `.then()`.
I know that every promise has an either resolved or rejected state, and one can work with these. I don't get the concept of how to do this here, because `.then((resolve, reject)` is not allowed

**EDIT:**
I just tried this:

```
let newItem = Item.create(
        {name: req.body.newItem}).then(result => console.log("Success: " + result), (error) => console.log("Error: " + error));
```

which seems to be working. I think I haven't fully grasped the arrow concept then. I thought the equivalent to

```
function(a, b){
if(a){
do Something()
}else{ //so it has to be b
do otherThing()
}
```

would be `.then(a,b) => doSomething(),do otherThing()`

Comment: Soo... what is your question again?

Comment: If my EDIT approach is correct (or the correct way to do it and how you would write it in a working environment) and if there may be is some ELI5 explanation on the arrow notation, since even after reading mdn and javascript.info I still seem to not use it correct

Comment: With simple language, A promise has 3 states ( Pending, Rejected, FullyFilled or Resolved )
You can access resolve callback in THEN and Access reject callback in CATCH like this: ```MyPromise().then((args)=>{... my codes }).catch((args)=>{ ... });```Also there is Spread too. You need to study functional programming in JS.

Comment: If you are disturbed by the arrow notation you can replace it by the classical one `function(x){ do something with x}` and go to arrows when you have fully understood how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Promises, you have (not only) two methods that in most cases are all you need:

- [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) - which receives a callback function when the Promise resolves, and a callback function when the Promise rejects. If you omit the second callback and the Promise rejects, an error will be rethrown and will need to be handled further
- [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) - which receives a callback function when the Promise rejects

In your case, the `.create()` Promise may be fulfilled or be rejected (those are not all states a Promise can have). To handle both cases, you can chain `.then()` and `.catch()` like this:

```
Item.create({name: req.body.newItem })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('resolved', result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     handleError(error);
  })
```

or like this:

```
Item.create({name: req.body.newItem })
  .then(
      (result) => {
          console.log('resolved', result);
      },
      (error) => {
         handleError(error);
      }
  );
```

Both approaches are equivalent.

In general, the Promises handling looks like this:

```
somethingReturnsPromise()
    .then((result) => {
        // handle result
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
    });
```

But that's not all about Promises. I suggest you read more about them, for instance, [this article](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-promises-in-javascript-13d99df067c1).

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. I didn't think of the equivalence to the catch behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Other answers greatly describes how promises work. But if you need to do this:

> What I actually want is to have the same code as above, that means using the (err, small) and incorporating that into my .then()

You can simply call the function with a null err parameter from the promise:

```
const existingFunction = (err, small) => { /* Do stuff */ }

Item.create({name: req.body.newItem })
  .then(newItem => {
    existingFunction(null, newItem)
  })
  .catch(err => {
     existingFunction(err)
  })
```